# Linde drawable buggy?

Tags: android, line, drawable

I am trying to draw a dotted/dashed horizontal line. On my table (Android 4.0.4) it shows up the way I intended, on my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2.2) it shows up as a solid line. Is that a bug in Android 4.2.2 or am I doing somethind wrong? In case you are wondering, I pruned the code to the bare minimum while searching for the cause of this bug.

Here is the code:

```
package com.aschenbrenner.dashlinetest;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

line drawable dashes.xmlt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
   <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="#f5dcb2"  android:dashWidth="2dip" android:dashGap="20dip"/>
</shape>
```

Layout activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView   
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:src="@drawable/dashes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I run across this problem, but I can't remember when.

I found this about the problem:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944

Basically you have to turn hardware acceleration off. Does this work?

Comment: @user611923 Thanks. Don't forget to mark the question as solved.